# Matrix representation of a linear map with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Consider the map $$f : \Bbb R^2 → \Bbb R^2, \quad (x, y) → (2x − 3y, x + y) $$
> Consider the vectors $$ v = \begin{pmatrix}
>     1 \\
>     -3 \\
>     \end{pmatrix} \; and \; w = \begin{pmatrix}
>     2 \\
>     1 \\
>     \end{pmatrix}$$
> Compute $$ f_{[e_{\Bbb R^2}]→[v,w]}. $$

I am not sure how to go about solving this problem.  I tried two approaches.  The first one was
$$ f_{[e_{\Bbb R^2}] → [e_{\Bbb R^2}]} ⋅ Id_{[e_{\Bbb R^2}]→[v,w]} $$
From this I got the following result
$$ \begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\4/7&-1/7\end{bmatrix} $$
For the second approach I got the result
$$ \begin{bmatrix}15/7&-5/7\\31/7&6/7\end{bmatrix} $$

I am not sure whether either of these is correct.  How does one go about solving this problem?

Comment: It's always good to provide a definition of your notations since different schools often use different notations. For instance, I might take my time to think of what $f_{[e_{\Bbb R^2}]→[v,w]}$ is. But if you define it with a few more words, everything will be fine and faster.

Comment: @VIVID We defined [ℝ2]→[ℝ2] as the matrix representation with respect to the standard basis [ℝ2].  Part of my problem is that I am not quite sure what the question is asking.  Nonetheless, [ℝ2]→[,], I believe is asking for the matrix representation of  with respect to the basis [ℝ2] and [,].